# Generating a JavaScript array using elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I manipulate a JavaScript array based on what elements I have in a container, and what order they are in?

See: http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/item-purchase-planner

Clicking an item will move it into the "Item Sandbox", which generates or manipulates the "item" array (seen in the URL/permalink). Re-sorting any of the items inside the sandbox (debugging) reveals that the array is generated from the elements inside that container.

Edit: I guess I should explain my intentions? I'm currently working on a similar system, but was using array IDs on elements to manipulate the array. However, when I removed an element (and its value in the array) the other array IDs would no longer be accurate, and produce undesirable results. The array may contain duplicates, so I cannot use the values themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option you have is to create an empty div for the sandbox, and every time you add an item to the sandbox, you create a new element and append to that empty div. Hence, make it visible and then you can generate an array from the children elements found the that sandbox div. In the meanwhile, you can decide whether or not to make invisible on the right div (source of the children elements)

As for the order of display, it depends on whether you are prepending or appending children elements. To be honest, I would suggest you to review some basic JavaScript and rephrase your questions

Angela

Comment: I forgot I could use children to do this -_- ..thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The items in the list are shown and hidden by their classes.

Click on the **Magic Resist** button, and this is essentially what happens:

```
$(".tier-wrapper").not(".magic-resist").hide();
```